# Update number field by adding new CPT action

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I'm developing a WordPress plugin and I'm stuck on something.

I created two custom post types, the first one is "Clients" and the second one is "Actions clients".

In the "Clients" CPT, I added a ACF number field to store the number of available credits.
In the "Actions clients" CPT, I list different actions with credits assigned to each of them.

By adding a new client action, I want update the total of available credits in the first CPT. Like $totalCredits = $totalCredits - $actionCredits.

I tried different codes :

```
    //UPDATING DATA ACF FIELDS
    public function update_data_acf($post_id) {
        $field_key = get_field('credits_disponibles');// credits available
        // credits_available - credits number (of an action)
        $value = get_field('credits_disponibles') - get_field('nombre_de_credits');
        update_field( 'credits_disponibles', $value, $post_id );
        return $field_key;
    }
```

Or like this :

```
    public function update_credits_acf( $post_id ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    $post_status = get_post_status( $post_id );
    if ( $post_type == 'npluginclients' ) {

        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'npluginclients');

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                $number_of_credits_available = get_field('credits_disponibles', the_ID());
            $number_of_credits = count(get_field('nombre_de_credits', the_ID()));
            $number_of_credits_left = $number_of_credits_available - $number_of_credits;
            update_field('credits_disponibles', $number_of_credits_left, the_ID());

        endwhile;
    }
    }
```

Then I'm using this (Boiler Plate Plugin Generator ):

```
        $this->loader->add_action( 'acf/save_post', $plugin_admin, 'update_credits_acf' );
```

I'm probably making a lot of big mistakes, but I'm new in developing.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: `the_ID` will echo the output, it would appear at first glance that you want `get_the_ID()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating this post because I find a way to accomplish my goal :

```
public function update_credits_acf( $post_id ) {

$post_id = 137; // post_id of my CPT post

$number_of_credits_available = get_field('credits_available', $post_id);
$number_of_credits_action = get_field('number_of_credits');
$number_of_credits_left = $number_of_credits_available - $number_of_credits_action;

update_field('credits_available', $number_of_credits_left, $post_id);
```

This code works, now my question is : How to dynamically retrieve the id of my CPT ? I have several posts so I can't let "$post_id = 137;".

I tried some actions with get_the_ID(), the_ID()...